# Correct way to override django model form fields?

Tags: python-2.7, django-models, django-forms, field, overriding

I have a model:

```
class accounts(models.Model):
    ksize = models.PositiveIntegerField(default='100')
```

and I have a form:

```
class AccountsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = accounts
        fields = "__all__"
    ksize = forms.IntegerField(min_value=100)
```

the `min_value` option could not be specified in the `accounts` class but I didn't want to remove the `ksize` field completely because... I needed it.

It seems to be working, I have a default value in the form field when displayed as expected and it has a minimum allowed value.

But I am mixing `PositiveIntegerField` and `IntegerField` and I haven't seen any documentation about using this method either.

Can someone please tell me if this is safe/sensible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want worry about mixin types. Because PositiveIntegerField is like an IntegerField. It has only positive values from 0 to 2147483647